# Calculate if image dimensions are too horizontal or vertical

Tags: image-processing, ratio

I'm working on a PHP script that adds images to articles automatically. A common problem I've encountered is that the image dimensions can be too wide or too tall.

In terms of aspect ratio of **wide** images, I don't want it to be beyond `300x200` pixels:

[image]

So for example, the following dimensions are okay:

> 1000x700
>
> 100x80
>
> 200x300

The following are **bad**:

> 100x50
>
> 500x200
>
> 1200x700

Those are *too* wide pictures.

In terms of tall pictures, I don't want the image to be taller than a `100x200` aspect ratio:

[image]

So, `500x900` is fine, but `500x1005` is not.

What type of calculation can I do to determine if the picture is way too wide, way to tall, or acceptable?

I have `$width` and `$height` variables that I can use in this calculation.

Comment: Can't you just look at the ratio of the height vs the width?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Can you please post an answer demonstrating this solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP, but something like the following (change the thresholds to your liking)

```
if $width / $height > 1.5, then
  image is too wide
else if $width / $height < 0.7, then
  image is too tall
else
  image is acceptable
```